# Using patent #US2002002659

Tags: ownership

I have an idea that seems to fit well with the claims made in the patent US20020032659. I need to know how to use this patent. I have not been able to connect with anyone who knows about this patent and yet the claims made and description of the patent describe a very useful invention to simplify the process of developing new products. Can you give any kind of instructions on how to proceed and connect with the owner of this patent? thank you, jim

Comment: A business method patent for a Non Practicing Entity (the polite term)? While it t would be instructional to watch such businesses be enjoined in suit over the patent, Patent Application Information Retrieval (PAIR) shows it's status as abandoned for failure to respond to an Office Action in 2005. It's not a granted patent. The Help Center [Asking](http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "Asking") tells us your request is not on topic for this site.

Comment: The prosecution history shows it's claims 1-12 are rejected as anticipated by U.S. patent 6,298,327 which expired in 2009 due to non-payment of maintenance fees.